# Visual Studio 2017 project and angular global styles with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm creating angular application with Visual Studio 2017. I have used angular 4 project template, which I upgraded to angular 5.
The only problem which I am facing is how to add my custom global styles.css to application? I already added import 'styles.css' in app.browser.modules.ts so it is in dependency tree - I can see it is exported to main-client.js in wwwroot/dist folder.
But... it doesn't work. Googling tells me only that this way included styles should automaticaly appear in my index.html header styles section, but I am using Razor Views/Home/Index.cshtml so I get also get data from asp.net core on start.

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us what you have tried till now please. Any code?

Comment: I have the same problem, also with Angular5 in VS2017.
The problem is that the template does not include a "global" src/styles.css as created by the angular CLI and it is not clear at all where this could be added in webpack configuration.

Comment: Recently with upgraded to angular 6 I have created new angular CLI project and simply use ng serve in console window and then run debug from visual studio 2017. It work much, much faster and is definately better idea to do it.
Just forget about old angular 4 template for visual studio 2017, it's just rubbish when you try to use it with latest angular.